# Bind an event to the component - React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I have a Component like this:

```
class GlobalComponent extends React.Component{
    select= (e) => {
        this.props.select(); // must be implemented in another component and not parent
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.data}
                    <Button onClick={this.select}>Select</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return  state.data
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    select: () => dispatch(select()),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GlobalComponent );
```

I am importing this component in the root of my app - `app.js` like this:

```
<GlobalComponent />
```

The problem is this action`select`. I know I can pass it from global state or parent component with props (for the example):

```
<GlobalComponent select={this.select} />
```

or with `mapDispatchToProps`

, but the problem is that the component is defined only in one place, otherwise I need to import the `GlobalComponent` in almost all components.
What I want is to import the component once (somewhere in the root) and then somehow in a component that uses `GlobalComponent` define a function, which will NOT execute `select`, but implement select and it is only for the click event in the GlobalComponent:

```
export default class ComponentThatUsesGlobal extends React.Component {

    executeWhenGlobalComponentBtnIsClicked = () => {

    }
}
```

Is this possible and is it good approach or it is better just to import the component everywhere ?

I am using and `Redux`.

Comment: Why not just create a helper function and import it as needed?

Comment: This function needs to manipulate the state of the current component, where is defined.

Comment: I am a little bit confusing about your problem. do you want to do something else when select is triggered? I would suggest you to develop middleware to listen on action dispatched by select.

Comment: And you'll be using it in the current component where you can access and mutate its state.  So what's the issue?

Comment: Image that this `GlobalComponent` is a gallery - someone select an image and press select button. This image must be applied in the image profile component, for the example, but there are many components like image profile component and one gallery.

Comment: I am not sure that this will do the trick, because, it doesn't depend on global state change. It is just a function that needs to be bind to the click event, but there are many components with that function and only one GlobalComponent imported with a button.